# Instead of typing out each value for query I'm doing, can I match columns from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

SQL Server: I'm trying to match rows in `Table1` to values found in `data` and `popular_data` columns of `Table2`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ColumnX IN (872510, 872511, 872512, 872513, 872514,
                  872515, 879529, 879530, 879959, 
                  879960, 879961, 879962, 879963)
```

Is there anyway to simplify this into ColumnY and ColumnZ without typing out all the values? My actual query has over 500+ values so it is outrageous.

```
+--------+--------------+
|  data  | popular_data |
+--------+--------------+
| 872510 |       879962 |
| 872514 |       879963 |
| 872511 |              |
| 872515 |              |
| 872512 |              |
| 879529 |              |
| 872513 |              |
| 879530 |              |
| 879959 |              |
| 879960 |              |
| 879961 |              |
+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do it;

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColumnX in (

SELECT DISTINCT ColumnY FROM Table2 UNION

SELECT DISTINCT ColumnZ FROM Table2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table1 t1 
join table2 t2 
  on t1.ColumnX = t2.data 
  or t1.ColumnX = t2.popular_data
```